# Finding the density of a function of the standard normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X=Z^2$ (Z being the standard normal distribution),
$$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$$

Which is the same as:

$$F_X(x)=P(-\sqrt{x}\leq Z\leq \sqrt{x})$$

So the CDF is given by the difference in probabilities $\phi(\sqrt{x})-\phi(\sqrt{x})$.

Differentiating should give the PDF:

$$f_x(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{-0.5}\phi(\sqrt{x})+\frac{1}{2}x^{-0.5}\phi(-\sqrt{x})$$

At this point I don't know where to go. My textbook goes further and eliminates the $\phi$'s, but how do you come up with a $z$ value for variables? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: CDF of $X$ involves $\Phi$, not $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi (x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}e^{-x^{2}/2}$ so $f_X(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}x^{-0.5} e^{-x/2}$

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show how you came up with that? I don't quite follow.